# HTML div is not showing in some devices

Tags: php, html, adblock

I have a div in my page like

```
<div class="single-ad">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="ad-box featured-border">
        <h1><?=$model->title?></h1>
        <div class="short-history">
           <ul>
              <li>Published on: <b><?=$model->date?></b></li>
              <li>Category: <b><a href="#">Boats</a></b></li>
              <li>Location: <b>London</b></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Listing Slider  -->
    <div class="flexslider single-page-slider">
        <div class="flex-viewport">
             <?php
                 $images=$model->images;
             ?>
             <ul class="slides slide-main">
                <?php
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                         echo '<li class=""><img alt="" src="uploads/'.$image.'" title=""></li>';
                      }
                 ?>
              </ul>
           </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Listing Slider Thumb -->
     <div class="flexslider" id="carousels">
          <div class="flex-viewport">
               <ul class="slides slide-thumbnail">
                   <?php
                       foreach ($images as $image) {
                          echo '<li class=""><img alt="" src="uploads/'.$image.'" title=""></li>';
                                }
                                ?>
                              </ul>
              </div>
       </div>
                        <!-- Share Ad  -->


       <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- Short Description  -->
        <div class="ad-box">
             <p>
                 <?=$model->description?>
             </p>

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My website is for listing services the users are doing.The above div is to view an ad posted by the user.
In some devices this div is hidden.What will be the problem.Is this div blocked by some adblocker or something like that.?? And how to solve this issue??.Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the content of the <div>, without knowing this it can be difficult to say the reason why. I assume an ad? Is this ad static, javascript powered, or Flash?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be running into display issues due to the slider, which can be tricky business. Depending on the slider you use, it may hide itself or explode (show all content statically) on smaller screens or browsers with compatibility issues (I'm glancing at you internet explorer). I have seen this kind of strange behaviors through plugins on wordpress sites.

Consider using the popular Owl Carousel Library:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Or, if you do not like JQuery like me, there are many a good vanilla js silders out there:
https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

Please also make all relative URLs relative to the public root, or when you eventually move the page to another directory it will break the page.